# Display data from Twitter API using axios

Tags: api, vue.js, twitter, axios

I got stuck with a Vue project. I need to display 10 tweets in a component with the hashtag "Vue", so I am trying to pull data (username, tweet, date) from Twitter API. I read the twitter dev documentation, googled for hours, but it all suggested a php or python script for handling this request. Isn't it possible with axios? I got the following code, but the server always responds 400.

Here is my sample code (the keys are mocked):

```
import axios from "axios";

var api_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Atwitterdev&result_type=mixed&count=2";
var AUTH_OBJ = {
  oauth_consumer_key: "CONSUMER_KEY",
  oauth_nonce: "kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
  oauth_signature: "tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
  oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp: "1318622958",
  oauth_token: "TOKEN_FROM TWITTER_DEV",
  oauth_version: "1.0"
};

axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = AUTH_OBJ;

function getData() {
  axios.get(api_url)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
  });
}
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Maybe this isn't recommend to use in a browser, because it can expose your tokens and secrets keys. Try to use axios with Node.

Comment: You will not be able to do this from a browser, because the Twitter does not allow CORS.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your help! I will try python then.